# How to evaluate the following expression in jQuery without eval()?

Tags: jquery, eval

I have the following code that doesn't seem to be OK in context of jQuery:

```
jQuery.expr[ ":" ].containsNoCase = function( el, i, m ) {
    var search = m[ 3 ];
    if( !search ) return false;
    return eval( "/" + search + "/i" ).test( jQuery( el ).text() );
};
```

Is there any other way to return result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want

```
new RegExp(search, "i").test(jQuery(el).text());
```